# create dynamic invoice bill using mpdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf, mpdf

**[MPDF](http://www.binarytides.com/create-pdf-from-html-using-mpdf-in-php/)**

```
$html='
<body>
<div id="page">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.danifer.com/"><img src="./HTML Invoice Template_files/invoice_logo.jpg"></a>
  </div><!--end logo-->

  <div id="address">

    <p><strong>'.$company.'</strong><br>
    <a href="mailto:'.$dbobj->getAdminEmail().'">'.$dbobj->getAdminEmail().'</a>
    <br><br>
    Transaction # xxx<br>
    Created on 2008-10-09<br>
    </p>
  </div><!--end address-->

  <div id="content">
    <p>
      <strong>Customer Details</strong><br>
      Name: '.$dbobj->UserFullName().'<br>
      Email: '.$dbobj->UserEmail().'<br>
      Contact: '.$dbobj->UserContact().'<br>
      Payment Type: MasterCard    </p>
    <hr>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Qty</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Unit Price</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>Product 1</td>
        <td>1</td>
         <td>Rs 1495.00</td>
        <td>Rs 1495.00</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>Product 2</td>
        <td>1</td>
       <td>Rs 1495.00</td>
        <td>Rs 1495.00</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
          <td>Product 3</td>
          <td>1</td>
         <td>Rs 1495.00</td>
        <td>Rs 1495.00</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Rs 24485.00</strong></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody></table>


    <hr>
    <p>
      Thank you for your order.<br>
      If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us at <a href="mailto:'.$dbobj->getAdminEmail().'">'.$dbobj->getAdminEmail().'</a>.
    </p>

    <hr>
    <p>
      </p><center><small>This communication is for the exclusive use of the addressee and may contain proprietary, confidential or privileged information. If you are not the intended recipient any use, copying, disclosure, dissemination or distribution is strictly prohibited.
      <br><br>
      © '.$dbobj->sitename.' All Rights Reserved
      </small></center>
    <p></p>
  </div><!--end content-->
</div>
</body>;
```

**please i am already embeded mpdf lib in a website.
Now i want to generate dynamic pdf's for invoice . 
how to build dynamic table to $html variable? then i should pass it to WriteHTML()**

```
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Then i will call $mpdf->Output('downloads/application.pdf','F'); to download pdf

**SQL PART**

```
select desc,qty,price,total from orders where productid=1
```

PHP PART

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('downloads/application.pdf','F');
```

**i am using mysql**

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic? You use a form that users fill it than render a pdf or some kind of database structure?

Comment: i have to built tables from database.

Comment: Make queries to db, and print them into $html variable. Btw your question is unclear. We can not help you with less details.

Comment: what kind f details you want i will post here and please show me how to construct table in html variable

Comment: Show your php side and sql queries for printing into pdf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60328/discussion-between-dinu1389-and-hddntha).

Comment: I am not able to chat atm sorry. I will answer your question.

Comment: kk i will wait for your answer

Comment: Can you please show your php side of database connection? Do u use pdo or mysqli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have my cellphone to write this, so the code may be no perfect.

Use a foreach loop to iterate over your query results to construct a $htmlRows string. You didn't show us your php command to query and the result variable. So I assume $rows as an array of records.

```
$htmlRows = "";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $htmlRows .= "
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        <td>".$row->desc."</td>
        <td>".$row->qty."</td>
        <td>Rs ".$row->price."</td>
        <td>Rs ".$row->total."</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Do this loop before you generate $html.

Then when you assing the code to $html just replace all the non dynamic rows by

```
$html = " ....
    .....</tr>" 
    . $htmlRows 
    . "<tr>...."
;
```

Comment: i should add like this right?
$html = " ....
    .....</tr>" 
    . $htmlrows 
    . "<tr>...."
;

Comment: Of course the .... are just placeholdes for what you have had already before you asked. Hope you can figure it out now on your own.